# I'd like someone to help me understand a few lines of code

Tags: python

Can any one here please this code with example if its possible what this code doing?

```
def sort_by_length(words):
    t = []
    for word in words:
       t.append((len(word), word))
    t.sort(reverse=True)

    res = []
    for length, word in t:
      res.append(word)
    return res
```

and what the meaning of reverse =True what reverse is i do understand what men len and append method but return but what he ment by reverse

Comment: It's better to tell others what you already know

Comment: What does the function name tell you ? Read the code as plain english language.

Comment: Please consult the Python documentation.

Comment: `reverse`, as the name suggests, sorts the list in reverse order, i.e., descending.

Comment: Can you please use punctuation. I have trouble understanding what the actual question is. This sentence no verb.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning a list of words, sorted longest-to-shortest then z-to-a.

You could do the same thing with just

```
def sort_by_length(words):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda w: (len(w), w), reverse=True)
```

It might make more sense to sort longest-to-shortest, a-to-z, which would be

```
def sort_by_length(words):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda w: (-len(w), w))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_by_length(words):
t = [] # empty list
for word in words:# iterating over given words
   t.append((len(word), word)) # appending a word into the list "t" as tupel. e.g word "hello" as (5, "hello")
t.sort(reverse=True) # sorts all tupels in reverse-order

res = []
for length, word in t:
  res.append(word) # extracts just the words out of the tupels e.g. (5, "hello") => "hello"
return res # return words ordered
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort words by length

```
w = ["abcd", "za", "wyya", "dssffgdg"]
print sort_by_length(w);
```

http://ideone.com/jRzatV